# How to lock a global array in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

If I have a global array:

```
var users = new Array();
```

And I want to maintain that array amongst all my clients:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    users.push(socket.id);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
});
```

What if I have another function:

```
socket.on('new_score', function(s) {
    for (u in users) {
        ...
        do some processing
        ...

        io.sockets.connected[users[u]].emit('new_score', socket.id, s);

        ...
        do some processing
        ...
    }
});
```

Since socket.io is asynchronous, by the time I call emit in this last function, the user may have been deleted in disconnect.

So I need a way to safely access the array with all these other functions manipulating it asynchronously...

Comment: It would depend on what _"do some processing"_ actually means.

Comment: i.e. it does something that takes a while to complete

Comment: Does that mean the processing is async?

Comment: No, it's standard procedural code, though it does fire off a few emits to the clients

Comment: but again you are only emitting to the connected users at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the entire `for` loop is synchronous (or doesn't depend on results from async functions), you have nothing to worry about.

The entire loop will be processed in the same "tick" and any messages (like `disconnect`) will be handled at the end of the tick.

Comment: Wouldn't it mean that even if a user has disconnected while the server was for instance processing the for loop, the user still gets sent the event in for loop? If this is true wouldn't that cause a problem?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal the problem that the OP is refering to has to do with accessing the `users` array, which they shouldn't worry about (_iff_ the loop is synchronous). Of course, a user can disconnect in the mean time, but that won't change the `users` array during the loop (only afterwards). Emiting may cause the server to notice the user isn't connected anymore, but that won't be a big issue either (`socket.io` will handle that).

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if socket.io will crash the server. Up you go!